# Using a Javascript Map as data in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to set the datum of svg rectangles using a js Map, but it isnt working. I think the "d.key" is wrong but not sure. I want the map key to be the data at this point. I'm not getting any errors, it's just not creating them.

The data:

```
    const music = new Map();
    music.set("2345",{str:"4",fret:"6"});
    music.set("5478",{str:"5",fret:"2"});
    music.set("4317",{str:"4",fret:"3"});
    music.set("3455",{str:"5",fret:"12"});
    localStorage.setItem("testMusic",JSON.stringify(Array.from(music.entries())));
```

EDIT: Not working either. Does not create any rect on svg with id of demo1. I know they would overlap at this point. Also hovering over d in chrome dev tools shows nothing. data is available
The code:

```
 function createNoteRectOnStaff()
{
    let data = new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.testMusic));
    d3.select("#demo1")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data,d=>d)
    .enter()
    //.join("rect")
    .append("rect")
    //.attr('id',d=> d[0]) 
    .attr('x', 30)
    .attr('y', 60)
    .attr('width', 30)
    .attr('height', 60)
    .attr('stroke', 'green')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'butt')
    .attr('stroke-width', '1')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    

}
```

...

I tried this also:

```
.data(d3.keys(data))
```

but when I step into that d3 function, it doesnt recognized them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data(music)` or `data(music, d => d)` and extract data from the `Map` per the example below.

```js
const music = new Map();
music.set("2345",{str:"4",fret:"6"});
music.set("5478",{str:"5",fret:"2"});
music.set("4317",{str:"4",fret:"3"});
music.set("3455",{str:"5",fret:"12"});

d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(".item")
  .data(music, d => d) // or just .data(music)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(d => {
    const key = d[0];
    const str = d[1].str;
    const fret = d[1].fret;
    return [key, str, fret].join(" : ");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In the [source for data.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/src/selection/data.js) there is a function called `arraylike` that will return an array from a `Map` with `Array.from(Map)` which (I assume) is what is at play here. You can see a simple `Array.from(music)`:

```js
const music = new Map();
music.set("2345",{str:"4",fret:"6"});
music.set("5478",{str:"5",fret:"2"});
music.set("4317",{str:"4",fret:"3"});
music.set("3455",{str:"5",fret:"12"});

console.log(Array.from(music));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks @Robin-Mackenzie this did the trick     const data = Array.from(new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.testMusic)));